# Function to plot multiple lines in ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am trying to create a function that takes a sequence of x values and vector to be used in an equation. For each value in the vector `dM`, I would like to calculate probabilities of each x value occurring (equation in function for loop). Put all probabilities in a data.frame with associated `dM` values (so two columns) and then use ggplot to map the line to show each relationship.

For example: `pred_prob(0,870,50,c(-100,0))` this would mean from 0 to 870 by 50, calculate the probabilities for each value in the vector. Here is my working code. I suspect the nested for loop is not working as intended or how the data being stored is not correct.

```
pred_probs <- function(from,to,by,dM){
  pred_females = numeric(0)
  dM <- as.vector(dM)
  x_values <- seq(from = from, to = to, by = by)

  for( j in dM){
   for(i in x_values){
     prob=exp(-2.048e-02*i + 2.087e-02*j + -2.216e-05*i*j)/(1 + exp(-2.048e-02*i + 2.087e-02*j + -2.216e-05*i*j)) 
     pred_females = c(pred_females,prob,j)
   }
  pred_females <- as.data.frame(pred_females)
  ggplot(pred_females) + 
    geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x_values, y = pred_females, 
                            group = j, 
                            color = j))
  }
}
pred_prob(0,870,50,c(-100,0))
```

EDIT:

Output graph should look like this (only tw:
[image: Group and color variable corresponds to the dM value in the vector]

EDIT (again):
This function satisfies my needs:

```
pred_probs <- function(to, from, by, dep){
tibble() %>% 
  expand(j=dep, i=seq(to, from, by)) %>% 
  mutate(prob=exp(-2.048e-02*i + 2.087e-02*j + -2.216e-05*i*j)/(1 + exp(-2.048e-02*i + 2.087e-02*j + -2.216e-05*i*j))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = i, y = prob, color = as.factor(j)))
}
pred_probs(0,870,50,c(-300,-200,-100,0,100))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do as there are several issues with your code, but I'm pretty confident that you can do what you want without any need for loops or functions.

Does this come close to what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble() %>% 
  expand(i=c(-200, -100, 0, 100), j=seq(0, 2000, 50)) %>% 
  mutate(prob=exp(-2.048e-02*i + 2.087e-02*j + -2.216e-05*i*j)/(1 + exp(-2.048e-02*i + 2.087e-02*j + -2.216e-05*i*j))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = i, y = prob, color = as.factor(j)))
```

[image]

Comment: yes this is precisely what I need except switch the letters i and j in the expand.grid to plot lines for the different values in my vector and not the sequence. I am making a function because it will be necessary to change the values of the sequence and vector of values. I edited your code into a function. I posted the final function in my question that works. Thanks for the help!